# "Retrieve a blob, and its metadata": Does the get_blob() already cause file size dependent traffic on the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Quote from the Python code example at [View and edit object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) --> "Code Samples" --> "Python": `Retrieve a blob, and its metadata`.

The full code:

```py
from google.cloud import storage


def blob_metadata(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Prints out a blob's metadata."""
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    # blob_name = 'your-object-name'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Retrieve a blob, and its metadata, from Google Cloud Storage.
    # Note that `get_blob` differs from `Bucket.blob`, which does not
    # make an HTTP request.
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

    print("Blob: {}".format(blob.name))
    print("Bucket: {}".format(blob.bucket.name))
    print("Storage class: {}".format(blob.storage_class))
    print("ID: {}".format(blob.id))
    print("Size: {} bytes".format(blob.size))
    print("Updated: {}".format(blob.updated))
    print("Generation: {}".format(blob.generation))
    print("Metageneration: {}".format(blob.metageneration))
    print("Etag: {}".format(blob.etag))
    print("Owner: {}".format(blob.owner))
    print("Component count: {}".format(blob.component_count))
    print("Crc32c: {}".format(blob.crc32c))
    print("md5_hash: {}".format(blob.md5_hash))
    print("Cache-control: {}".format(blob.cache_control))
    print("Content-type: {}".format(blob.content_type))
    print("Content-disposition: {}".format(blob.content_disposition))
    print("Content-encoding: {}".format(blob.content_encoding))
    print("Content-language: {}".format(blob.content_language))
    print("Metadata: {}".format(blob.metadata))
    print("Custom Time: {}".format(blob.custom_time))
    print("Temporary hold: ", "enabled" if blob.temporary_hold else "disabled")
    print(
        "Event based hold: ",
        "enabled" if blob.event_based_hold else "disabled",
    )
    if blob.retention_expiration_time:
        print(
            "retentionExpirationTime: {}".format(
                blob.retention_expiration_time
            )
        )
```

From this `Retrieve a blob, and its metadata`, I read that blobs *might* already be more than metadata and more than the mere frame of the file object, so that they are already a loaded data object that leads to traffic on the Google Cloud Storage side at the size of the data. On the other hand, I see from [Reading only the metadata of a file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket into a Cloud Function in Python (without loading the file or its data!)](https://serverfault.com/a/1090964/607547) that there is no data loaded to the *Google Cloud Function* before calling `get_blob()` until you call `blob.download_to_filename()`, `blob.download_as_string()` or `blob.download_as_text()`. Is there still some traffic on the *Google Cloud Platform* when using `get_blob()`?

I am dealing with many large files try to log their metadata for further triggers inside and outside of GCP. I want to be sure that this get_blob() function's traffic is independent from the filesize of the file that it takes as the parameter.

Does the `get_blob()` already cause file size dependent traffic on the Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no traffic of the file content if you just get the blob and its metadata.

```
blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
```

does not yet upload the file to the cloud function since it is used for the metadata example query: [View and edit object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#view) --> "Code Samples" --> "Python". These code samples show it.

For more details, see [Reading only the metadata of a file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket into a Cloud Function in Python (without loading the file or its data!)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1090609/reading-only-the-metadata-of-a-file-in-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket-into-a-clou).